# scatterplot from two datasets in r

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I need to make one scatterplot from two datasets. So on x-axis the IBAQ values of dataset 1 and 2, and on the y-axis the proteins of dataset 1 and 2 (the protein names do not have to be visible on the y-axis). I also need to give the proteins from dataset 1 and 2 different colors. I also want to add a threshold line for the top 5% (IBAQ value) proteins.
here is an example plot:
[image]

I literally have nothing now except for the code for a plot of dataset 1.

[image]

UPDATE:
i combined my two datasets into 1. But now i still need to color the background proteins and the proteins of interest. So if row 1-200 in my dataset are the proteins of interest and row 201-700 are background proteins. How can I color them differently?
|protein.names|IBAQ|
| protein1    |4,3 |
| protein2    |4,5 |
| etc.        |etc.|
the scatterplot i have now:
[image]

Comment: could you please share the two datasets (or subsets of them..)

You can use a website like pastebin for this, it's very easy

Comment: Hi, im trying to figure out how to use pastebin. But for extra info in advance, my datasets are like this:                                                                                                                         dataset1:  protein.names  |   IBAQ score                                                                                   .                          gata1           4.3333                                                                                     .                            tal1             3.6666

Comment: To paste some data (or also just a few lines), you can also simply use `dput()` in R - then you can copy it into your question

Comment: im so sorry, i have no idea what im doing. So i just added a screen cap of my dataset. does that help?

Comment: i only need the columns protein.names and ibaq.extra1_strept_pd for my plot

Comment: @YingyingLaw in your console type `dput(head(df1))` and paste the output above. Do the same with your other dataset. i.e. `dput(head(enr.Bstrept1))`

Comment: @YingyingLaw  pastebin is very easy, just open your file as a text file, just copy the entire thing (control A), and copy it, and paste it to paste bin.  Afterworks, click "create paste" and copy the link here.   Do so with both datasets